# Conditional validation in rails using attr_accessor

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, ruby-on-rails-4, attr-accessor

I'm attempting to do some conditional validation in my model `Company`.  Basically the idea is that `Company` is used by a lot of different controllers, each with their own validation requirements.  My thought was to use `attr_accessor` to add an attribute that identifies the controller in question like so:

```
<%= company.hidden_field :controller_context, value: "incorporation" %>
```

However, I've been unable to use `:controller_context` as a condition in my validation.

```
validate :final_incorporation, if: "controller_context=='incorporation'"
```

The above gives me no errors but does not trigger validation either.  However, if I try to get the value of `controller_context` in my log with the following:

```
logger.debug "controller_context: #{controller_context}"
```

I get the error

```
undefined local variable or method `controller_context'
```

I've been looking around on google for a solution.  I've seen one recommendation to edit my controller to accommodate this but this doesn't seem optimal for a variety of reasons.  What might I be missing here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean when you say it is _used_ by a lot of controllers?

Comment: @JawadKhawaja Thanks for the response; this means that it's referenced by them.  Companies can be edited through incorporations, or cap tables, or by convertible notes.  All of which have their own specific requirements that need to be validated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your initial idea seems practical. I'm not entirely sure if the value of your hidden field is available in the model. Try it like this and let me know how it goes:

Add `attr_accessor :controller_context` to your model. In your controller, before calling save, assign your controller's name to `@company.controller_context`.

Then while validating in the model add a condition, like:
`validate :final_incorporation, if: :is_incorporation`

And in the method:

```
def is_incorporation?
  controller_context == 'incorporation'
end
```